# Завершения цикла

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста с задачкой, много вариантов перепробовал.

-Eсли пользователь ввел не число, спросить еще раз. в случае повтороного неправильного ввода - сказать ему что он не прав и завершиь программу.

В место int ставлю str начинает ругаться на цифры....

```
age = int(input('Enter age: '))
if (age < 18 ):
   print("Мы не продаем лкоголь несовершеннолетним!")
elif (age > 70):
    print("Вам в пенсионный отдел!")
elif (age >= 18) and (age < 70):
    print("Добро пожаловать")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
age = "None"
while not age.isdigit():
    age = input('Введите пожалуйста ваш возраст: ')
# Введите пожалуйста ваш возраст: 77

if age < '18':
    print("Молодым - везде у нас дорога!")
elif (age > '70'):
    print("Старикам — везде у нас почёт!")
else :
    print("Добро пожаловать хороший человек!")

# Старикам — везде у нас почёт!
```

---

**Update**

```
i = 2
age = "None"
while i and not age.isdigit():
    age = input('Введите пожалуйста ваш возраст: ')
    i -= 1

if not age.isdigit():
    print("Извините, но вы неправильно вводили ваш возраст.")
elif  int(age) < 18:
    print("Молодым - везде у нас дорога!")
elif int(age) > 70:
    print("Старикам — везде у нас почёт!")
else :
    print("Добро пожаловать хороший человек!")
```

Comment: кроме того, что вы стариков и детей обозвали нехорошими :), там еще просили закончить прогу после второй неверной попытки

Comment: =) ребят, не судите строго... учусь )))

Comment: @RostislavPopov это я не вам писал, а S.Nick

Comment: аааа, так это был мой текст))
Спасибо)))

Comment: Уважаемый @splash58 никогда и никого не обозвал нехорошими. Второе ваше замечание учел и исправился.

Comment: @S.Nick там вообще-то смайлик стоит :) я исключительно по поводу принтов

Answer (score 1):

добавь исключение **try**
можно почитать вот здесь про [исключение](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/isklyucheniya-v-python-konstrukciya-try-except-dlya-obrabotki-isklyuchenij.html)

```
try:
   age = int(input('Введите возраст: '))
except ValueError:
   try:
      age = int(input('Вы ввели не цифру, введите возраст: '))
   except ValueError:
      print("Это не число!")

if (age < 18 ):
   print("Мы не продаем лкоголь несовершеннолетним!")
elif (age > 70):
    print("Вам в пенсионный отдел!")
elif (age >= 18) and (age < 70):
    print("Добро пожаловать")
```